# REST new ID with DDD Aggregate

Tags: rest, architecture, aggregate, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

This question seemed fool at first sight for me, but then I realized that I don't have a proper answer yet, and interestingly also didn't find good explanation about it in my searches. 
I'm new to Domain Driven Design concepts, so, even if the question is basic, feel free to add any considerations to it.

I'm designing in Rest API to configure Server Instances, and I came up with a Aggregate called `Instance` that contains a List of `Configurations`, only one specific Configuration will be active at a given time.

To add a Configuration, one would call an endpoint `POST /instances/{id}/configurations` with the body on the desired configuration. In response, if all okay, it would receive a HTTP 204 with a Header Location containing the new Configuration ID.

I'm planning to have only one Controller, `InstanceController`, that would call `InstanceService` that would manipulate the Instance Aggregate and then store to the Repo.

Since the ID's are generated by the repository, If I call `Instance.addConfiguration` and then `InstanceRepository.store`, how would I get the ID of the newly created configuration? I mean, it's a List, so It's not trivial as calling `Instance.configuration.identity`

A option would implement a method in Instance like, `getLastAddedConfiguration`, but this seems really brittle.

What is the general approach in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the ID's are generated by the repository

You could remove this extra complexity. Since `Configuration` is an entity of the `Instance` aggregate, its `Id` only needs to be unique inside the aggregate, not across the whole application. Therefore, the easiest is that the Aggregate assigns the `ConfigurationId` in the `Instance.addConfiguration` method (as the aggregate can easily ensure the uniqueness of the new `Id`). This method can return the new `ConfigurationId` (or the whole object with the Id if necessary).

> What is the general approach in this situation?

I'm not sure about the general approach, but in my opinion, the sooner you create the Ids the better. For Aggregates, you'd create the Id before storing it (maybe a GUID), for entities, the Aggregate can create it the moment of creating/adding the entity. This allows you to perform other actions (eg publishing an event) using these Ids without having to store and retrieve the Ids from the DB, which will necessarily have an impact on how you implement and use your repositories and this is not ideal.

Comment: The possibility of using/referencing newly created entities without requiring a repository seems a very good aspect of the architecture. I'll wait for other answers to see, but thanks so far, didn't thought about that.